# AH10039: FastCGI: server and Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Multi SSL

Tags: .htaccess, fastcgi, multisite, domain-mapping

My shop is supposed to work on monday ... and it is not ready (yet). Stress ...

Recently I moved to **SSL** and remove the now useless **domain mapping** plugin.

I am experiencing various problems (  a) download of **downloadable files** on my WooCommerce shop often fail ,  b) the **theme** displayed on my main site homepage is not the one activated ...)
Debug mode is on but no error appears in my pages.

My logs are full of errors :

```
AH10039: FastCGI: server
```

and

```
server and Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

I suspect my htaccess to be causing at least the 2nd error. ( And I am pretty ignorant in that matter ...) Here it is :

```
#WFIPBLOCKS - Do not remove this line. Disable Web Caching in Wordfence to remove this data.
Order Deny,Allow
#Do not remove this line. Disable Web Caching in Wordfence to remove this data - WFIPBLOCKS
#SetEnv PHP_VER 5
#SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# ultimate hotlink protection
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$           [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?mainDomain\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?subDomain1\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?subDomain2\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?subDomain3\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?subDomain4\. [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$                             - [F,NC,L]
</ifModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks for any advice !

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Solved !
I simply went back to the standard .htaccess given in the network settings